# Text alignment in table with rotated text and Row height adjustment

Tags: tables, alignment

I made two payoff tables like below:
Here is the code I am using:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Payoffs:}
\end{center}
\vspace{-2em}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hspace{-2em}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$s=0$}\\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a=0$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a=1$} \\\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}*{}  & $r=0$ & $B$ & $B-c$ \\\cline{3-4}
& $r=1$ & $B$ & $B-c-k$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$ s=1 $}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a=0$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a=1$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}*{}  & $r=0$ & $-B$ & $B-c$ \\\cline{3-4}
  & $r=1$ & $-B$ & $B-c-k$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to add "(1-p)" and "p" to the right-most column of the table on the right like below:

[image]

I tried to add it but could not figure out how to do so. Can anyone please help me with this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions and comments:

- You could use `\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{...}` directives to rotate `(1-p)` and `(p)` by -90 degrees each.
- There appears to be a lot of needless overhead. I would get rid of the outer `tabular` environment and both `minipage` wrappers. The inner `tabular` environments appear to have an unneeded first column. Since the contents of the inner `tabular` environments are all typeset in math mode, consider switching to `array` environments and save a lot of keystrokes spent on typing various `$` symbols.

Note that the `array` environment on the right has an additional column when compared with the one on the left:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\blank{\mc{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Payoffs}
\end{center}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
$
\begin{array}{r|c|c|}
  \blank & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathbf{s=0}}\\[-1ex]
  \blank & \mc{a=0} & \mc{a=1} \\\cline{2-3}
  r=0 & B & B-c   \\\cline{2-3}
  r=1 & B & B-c-k \\\cline{2-3}
\end{array}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{array}{r|c|c|l}
  \blank & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathbf{s=1}}\\[-1ex]
  \blank & \mc{a=0} & \mc{a=1} \\\cline{2-3}
  r=0 & -B & B-c   & \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\scriptstyle(1-p)$} \\\cline{2-3}
  r=1 & -B & B-c-k & \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\scriptstyle(p)$}   \\\cline{2-3}
\end{array}
$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```